# Autolayouts : How to create collapse/Expand dynamic view swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout

I have a problem that I can't create a view that can collapse it's contents that may be dynamic height , i know it's easy to collapse it with height **constant = 0** , but i can't figure out how to make it expand again as the content of that view is dynamic and sub-itmes may be added later

I want that behavior

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Your answer has massively overcomplicated a very simple solution.

You should first create your `zeroHeightConstraint` as a property.

```
let zeroHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = dynamicView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
```

You could do this as an outlet from the storyboard too if you wanted.

Now add your button action...

```
@IBAction func toggleCollapisbleView() {
    if animationRunning { return }

    let shouldCollapse = dynamicView.frame.height != 0

    animateView(isCollapse: shouldCollapse,
                buttonText: shouldCollapse ? "Expand" : "Collapse")
}

private func animateView(isCollapse: Bool, buttonText: String) {
    zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = isCollapse

    animationRunning = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration duration: 1, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.animationRunning = false
        self.button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
    })
}
```

Always avoid using `view.tag` in your code. It should always be seen as "code smell". There is almost always a much more elegant way of doing what you are trying to do.

Regarding the bottom constraint. You should really be using a `UIStackView` to layout the contents of the inside of the view here. By doing that you no longer need to iterate the subviews of your `contentView` you can access the `UIStackView` directly. And do the same thing there. In fact... a much better way would be to create the `bottomConstraint` against the view using a `priority` less than `1000`. e.g. `999`.

By doing that you don't have to remove or add that constraint at all. When the `zeroHeightConstraint` is not active it will be there and work. When the `zeroHeightConstraint` is active it will override the bottom constraint automatically.