# expand UIView height bottom to left and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a view that has a button on top and a textview on bottom as subviews, Im trying to have the button either expand and show the textview or collapse and hide it (like a show/hide)

I used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150004/autolayouts-how-to-create-collapse-expand-dynamic-view-swift-3-4) and it kind of helped, except the subview (text view) was still showing and overlapping with other views so it only hid the main UIView.

here I initialized the height constraint to 25 to leave space for the button:
heightConstraint = detailView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25)

the action function that'll expand/collapse the view based on the height constraint

```
    @objc func expandViewPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if isAnimating { return }
    let shouldCollapse = detailView.frame.height > 25
    animateView(isCollapsed: shouldCollapse)
}
```

the animation function

```
private func animateView(isCollapsed: Bool) {
    heightConstraint[enter image description here][1].isActive = isCollapsed
    isAnimating = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.detailText.isHidden = isCollapsed
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (_) in
        self.isAnimating = false
    }
}
```

—

[expanded view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErBX7.png)

Comment: Use dynamic height constraint.

Comment: @user3344236 that's what I did, except it only changed the height of the main view but not its subviews.

Comment: If the text view is *"still showing and overlapping with other views"* it is likely the `UIView` that contains does **not** have `.clipsToBounds` set to `true`.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, this worked.. but I still got the [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error.

Answer (score 0):

Sherbini .. please make sure you have added proper constraints to your subviews .. make sure not to add height constraint on any of your subview ..

also make sure you have added view.clipsToBounds == true

Hope it will work for you ..

Comment: this did the trick, but now I got the [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints debug error instead..

Comment: it will be great if you will show the code or the view .. so that i can help you tosort this thing out .. Thanks !

Comment: I added a picture of the view in the question post

Comment: Ohh..it seems like you want to expand collaspe the table view cell right ??

Comment: No they aren't table view cells, they're just UIViews

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach this.

One method is to use two "bottom" constraints:

- one from the bottom of the button to the bottom of `detailView`
- one from the bottom of `detailText` to the bottom of `detailView`

Then set the constraint Priority of each based on whether the view should be "collapsed" or "expanded."

Here is a full implementation for you to try:

```
class ExpandViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let myButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Collapse", for: [])
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()
    
    let detailText: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.text = "This is text in the text view."
        return v
    }()
    
    let detailView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        return v
    }()

    var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var collapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var expandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        detailView.addSubview(myButton)
        detailView.addSubview(detailText)
        view.addSubview(detailView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // when collapsed, we want button bottom to constrain detailView bottom
        collapsedConstraint = myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0)
        
        // when expanded, we want textView bottom to constrain detailView bottom
        expandedConstraint = detailText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0)

        // we'll start in Expanded state
        expandedConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        collapsedConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain detailView Top / Leading / Trailing
            detailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            detailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            detailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // no Height or Bottom constraint for detailView
            
            // constrain button Top / Center / Width
            myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.centerXAnchor),
            myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            // constrain detailText Top / Leading / Trailing
            detailText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            detailText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            detailText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),

            // constrain detailText's Height
            detailText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            expandedConstraint,
            collapsedConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.expandViewPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func expandViewPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if isAnimating { return }
        animateView()
    }
    
    private func animateView() {
        isAnimating = true
        
        // if it's expanded
        if expandedConstraint.priority == .defaultHigh {
            expandedConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            collapsedConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        } else {
            collapsedConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            expandedConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
            detailText.isHidden = false
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (_) in
            self.detailText.isHidden = self.expandedConstraint.priority == .defaultLow
            self.isAnimating = false
            self.myButton.setTitle(self.detailText.isHidden ? "Expand" : "Collapse", for: [])
        }
    }
}
```